# Perl hash of hashes and array - print the array contents

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

Have the below data structure.  I want to print the entire array for the key TUESDAY.  Tried the below way but it's not working.  I don't want to have an additional statement of taking the array reference to a variable and printing out later. I want to do it in single statement in the print function.

```
my $FILE_LIMIT = {
    CHECK => "ON",
    ISANE => {
        CHECK     => "ON",
        MONDAY    => 33,
        TUESDAY   => [10, 20, 30, 40],
        WEDNESDAY => 12,
        THURSDAY  => 13,
        SATURDAY  => 14,
        SUNDAY    => 15
    } };

print "array val: " . $FILE_LIMIT->{ISBANE}->{TUESDAY}[1 .. $#] . "\n";
```

Comment: @JimGarrison: No, ISBANE ne ISANE :)

Comment: I'm a perl noob. Can we declare hash using `$` as well? I thought for hashes you use `%`.

Comment: @vidit - Yes, `$FILE_LIMIT` is a hash reference. Which is the reason for the dereference operator `->`.

Comment: @chrsblck - but hashes are declared using `%`, right?

Comment: @vidit - yes. but references will be declared with the `$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print "array val: " . join (' ', @{ $FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}->{TUESDAY} }), "\n";
```

Comment: I think you can drop the join - print "array val: @{$FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}->{TUESDAY}}\n";

Comment: @erickb - you are correct. since I'm joining with `whitespace`. It was done out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

As you have guessed, the array reference is at `$FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}{TUESDAY}`, so dereference it using

```
print "array val: @{$FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}{TUESDAY}}\n";
```

**output**

```
array val: 10 20 30 40
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print"  @{ $FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}->{TUESDAY}}\n";
```

output:

```
  10 20 30 40
```

---

you are basically trying to take out the array slice in your code, that is useful if you want to take out only specific elements of the array, try to understand the below code that would take out the some elements from the array.

```
my @test = @{ $FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}->{TUESDAY}};
print " @{$FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}->{TUESDAY}}[1 .. $#test] \n";
```

output:

```
20 30 40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $FILE_LIMIT = {
    CHECK => "ON",
    ISANE => {
        CHECK     => "ON",
        MONDAY    => 33,
        TUESDAY   => [10, 20, 30, 40],
        WEDNESDAY => 12,
        THURSDAY  => 13,
        SATURDAY  => 14,
        SUNDAY    => 15
    } };

print $_,"\n",foreach(@{$FILE_LIMIT->{ISANE}->{TUESDAY}});
```